# Angular | How to place ng-content/child content out of component using ng-template or any

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a tabbing component, defined in this
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabs-example

I'm trying to put ng-content from my-tabs to external ng-template, is there any way to do that ? can i assign ng-content to TemplateRef or ViewContainerRef.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can use `@ContentChild` form angular this will help you to pass the content from parent component to child - i will change your code a bit

tabs.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-tabs',
  template: `
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs" (click)="selectTab(tab)" [class.active]="tab.active">
        <a href="#">{{tab.title}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="parentList"></ng-template>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
    .tab-close {
      color: gray;
      text-align: right;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    `
  ]
})
export class TabsComponent implements AfterContentInit {

  @ContentChild('list') parentList: TemplateRef<any>;

 }
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <my-tabs>
      <my-tab [tabTitle]="'Tab 1'">
        Tab 1 content
      </my-tab>
      <ng-template #list>
          <my-tab tabTitle="Tab 2">
             Tab 2 content
          </my-tab>
      </ng-template>
    </my-tabs>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

The `<ng-template #list>` in the parent component will pass it's content inside the template to the child component - whereas the child component will read the content and place the content in the `<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="parentList"></ng-template>`

By this method you can pass as many content from parent to child - hope this helps you

Thanks - Happy coding !! - Check this link for further clarification https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild

Comment: Thanks for help, but what i want to do is getting these rendered components out of  my-tabs component and placing it anywhere in parent using templateref or anything like it.

what you are doing is passing template from parent to child and placing it in child.

Comment: yeah - you can read the template of the child component by `@ViewChild('templateName') templatePropName : TemplateRef<any>;` and to read this template from the parent you need to read the entire child component like this `@ViewChild(ChildComponentName) childPropName : ChildComponentName` - this will act as instance to the child component where you can read the template `this.childPropName.templatePropName` so you will get your template and you can place it anywhere in your parent - Ref [https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild][0]

Comment: Reference - [https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild

Comment: I have placed my solution. If you can suggest any improvements, those will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using code below, i'm using Output EventEmitter to get ng-content and placing it in a template in parent. Any suggestions are welcome, i need help to improve it.

**parent.component.html**

```
<sb-tabs contentMode="external" (templateAfterInit)="tabContentSet($event)">
   <sb-tab *ngIf="jobId" tabTitle="Invoices">
              Hello
   </sb-tab>
</sb-tabs>
```

Sidebar



    Content To Show

**parent.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild("tabContent")
  tabContent: TemplateRef<any>;
tabContentSet(event) {
    this.tabContent = event.template;
  }
```

**tabs.component.ts**

```
import {
      Component, AfterContentInit, ContentChildren, QueryList
      , Input, Output, ViewChild, EventEmitter
    } from '@angular/core';

    import { TabComponent } from './tab.component'

    enum TabContentMode { internal = 'internal', external = 'external' }

    @Component({
      selector: 'sb-tabs',
      template: `
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs {{cssClasses.tabsBar}}">
        <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let tab of tabs" (click)="selectTab(tab)">
          <a class="nav-link" [class.active]="tab.active">{{tab.title}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ng-container *ngIf="contentMode == 'internal'" [ngTemplateOutlet]="tabsContent">
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #tabsContent>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </ng-template>
    `
    })
    export class TabsComponent implements AfterContentInit {

      @Input() cssClasses: any = {
        tabsBar: 'nav nav-tabs'
      };

      @ContentChildren(TabComponent) tabs: QueryList<TabComponent>;

      @ViewChild("tabsContent")
      private externalTemplate: any;

      @Input() contentMode: TabContentMode = TabContentMode.internal;

      @Output("templateAfterInit")
      templateAfterInit = new EventEmitter();

      constructor() { }

      ngAfterContentInit(): void {

        this.templateAfterInit.emit({ template: this.externalTemplate });

        // get all active tabs
        let activeTabs = this.tabs.filter((tab) => tab.active);

        // if there is no active tab set, activate the first
        if (activeTabs.length === 0) {
          this.selectTab(this.tabs.first);
        }
      }

      selectTab(tab: TabComponent) {
        // deactivate all tabs
        this.tabs.toArray().forEach(tab => tab.active = false);

        // activate the tab the user has clicked on.
        tab.active = true;
      }

    }
```

**tab.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { fadeInOut } from '@shared/common/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'sb-tab',
  animations: [fadeInOut],
  template: `
    <div [@fadeInOut] *ngIf="active" class="pane">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `
})
export class TabComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('tabTitle') title: string;
  @Input() active = false;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```